# My pic is not displaying in vue.js but it shows image src

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, dom

This is my code and script:

```
<template>
    <div class="tasks_container">
        <div class="tasks_content">
            <h1>Tasks</h1>
            <ul class="tasks_list">
                <li v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id">
                    <h2>{{ task.name }}</h2>
                    
                    <img :src="task.pic" alt="No Image" title="Order Now" />

                    <p></p>
                    <button>
                    </button>
                    <button>Delete</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                // tasks
                tasks: ['']
               
               
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async getData() {
                try {
                    // fetch tasks
                    const response = await this.$http.get('http://localhost:8000/read_retrieve/');
                    // set the data returned as tasks
                    this.tasks = (response.data);
                    
                } catch (error) {
                    // log the error
                    console.log(error);
                }
            },
        },
        created() {
            // Fetch tasks on page load
            this.getData();
        }
    }
</script>
```

My response is correct from the API endpoint. It shows pic src but not displaying an image.

Comment: Check if your url image is correct, and check if you have some 404 errors in your browser console.

Comment: Yes my url is correct and i get {{task.name}} correctly but when i get image it shows only image src in inspect but not dispalying image

Comment: If task.pic is a url, try adding referrerpolicy="no-referrer" to your img element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add an absolute path to the image src, i mean like "img/task"

Comment: I solve my problem simply pass context={'request': request} in my django rest framework views.py. This is backend problem not client. Right now It works fine and displays image.